# how can i using image_cropper i have this error?

Tags: flutter, dart

[photo of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kTzLJ.png)List item

```
class UserImagePicker extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserImagePickerState createState() => _UserImagePickerState();
}

class _UserImagePickerState extends State<UserImagePicker> {
  final picker = ImagePicker();
  File _imageFile;
  String _currentImageUrl;

  // Future pickImage() async {
  //   final pickedFile = await picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
  //   setState(() {
  //     _imageFile = File(pickedFile.path);
  //   });
  // }

  Future uploadImage(BuildContext context) async {
    String fileName = basename(_imageFile.path);
    StorageReference storageReference =
    FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('images/$fileName');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = storageReference.putFile(_imageFile);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((val) {
      print('Dome:$val');
      setState(() {
        _currentImageUrl = val;
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: customColor,
      body: StreamBuilder<Users>(
        stream: DatabaseServices(userId: user.uid).userData,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            Users userData = snapshot.data;
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Stack(
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        height: 150,
                        width: 150,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              spreadRadius: 2,
                              blurRadius: 10,
                              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
                              offset: Offset(0, 10),
                            ),
                          ],
                          border: Border.all(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            width: 3,
                          ),
                        ),
                        child: CircleAvatar(
                          radius: 55,
                          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                          child: ClipOval(
                            child: SizedBox(
                              height: 150,
                              width: 150,
                              child: (_imageFile != null)
                                  ? FileImage(
                                      _imageFile,
                                    )
                                  : Image(
                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                        UserData.userImageUrl,
                                      ),
                                      fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                    ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        bottom: 0,
                        right: 0,
                        child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap: () {
                            _showPickOptionsDialog(context);
                          },
                          child: Container(
                            height: 35,
                            width: 35,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              shape: BoxShape.circle,
                              color: customColor,
                              border: Border.all(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                width: 2,
                              ),
                            ),
                            child: Icon(
                              Icons.edit,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: RaisedButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          ),
                          color: Colors.white,
                          child: Text(
                            getTranslated(context, 'save'),
                            style: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
                              color: customColor,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            DatabaseServices(userId: user.uid).updateUserData(
                              userData.phoneNumber,
                              userData.name,
                              userData.email,
                              _currentImageUrl ?? userData.userImageUrl,
                            );

                            DBHelper.saveUserSingIn(true);

                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => Home(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: FlatButton(
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                            side: BorderSide(
                              width: 1,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          child: Text(
                            getTranslated(context, 'skip'),
                            style: AppTheme.heading.copyWith(
                              color: Colors.white,
                            ),
                          ),
                          onPressed: () {
                            DBHelper.saveUserSingIn(true);

                            Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
                              MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (_) => Home(),
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              ),
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  _loadPicker(ImageSource source, BuildContext context) async {
    // ignore: deprecated_member_use
    File picked = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: source);
    if (picked != null) {
      _cropImage(picked, context);
    }
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }

  _cropImage(File picked, BuildContext context) async {
    File cropped = await ImageCropper.cropImage(
      androidUiSettings: AndroidUiSettings(
        statusBarColor: Colors.red,
        toolbarColor: Colors.red,
        toolbarTitle: "Crop Image",
        toolbarWidgetColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      sourcePath: picked.path,
      aspectRatioPresets: [
        CropAspectRatioPreset.original,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio16x9,
        CropAspectRatioPreset.ratio4x3,
      ],
      maxWidth: 800,
    );
    if (cropped != null) {
      setState(() {
        _imageFile = cropped;
        uploadImage(context);
      });
    }
  }

  void _showPickOptionsDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Pick from Gallery"),
              onTap: () {
                _loadPicker(ImageSource.gallery, context);
              },
            ),
            ListTile(
              title: Text("Take a pictuer"),
              onTap: () {
                _loadPicker(ImageSource.camera, context);
              },
            )
          ],[enter image description here][1]
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.vanillia">
    <!-- Flutter needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <activity
    android:name="com.yalantis.ucrop.UCropActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

error:
in photo
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.vanillia/c.e.a.j}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?, null, android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.vanillia/c.e.a.j}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: Disable obfuscation by adding `-dontobfuscate` to your `produard-rules.pro`, reproduce issue and edit log message in question

Comment: Where do I find this proguard-rules.pro file?@DimaRostopira

Comment: Inside `android/app` folder